# How to query for different fields in elasticserch?

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I want to query elasticsearch for one or two key:value pair such as:

```
http://localhost:9200/indexname/_search?pretty=1&q=Date:%222000-12-30T10:11:25%22&q=id:%22unique_id%22
```

This query takes only the unique_id into consideration. If I change the Date to any invalid value, still it gives me all values based on the Unique_id.

Any idea how to make an AND condition with both the queries? It should consider both queries and provide result accordingly? Please advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation, it should work

See http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/query-string-query.html

That said, you can create your query as below:

http://localhost:9200/indexname/_search?pretty=1&q=%2BDate%3A2000-12-30T10:11:25+%2Bid%3Aunique_id

Note : %2B is decoded as '+' whereas '+' is decoded as ' '

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
GET /index/type/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {"Date":"2015-09-17 03:45:00-04"}
  },
  "filter" : {
    "and" : [
                {
                        "match": {"unique_id" : "6324"}
                }
            ]
  }
}
```

Reference link -  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-and-query.html

Answer (score 0):

You can choose this query also ,(easy way)

```
GET   myindex/mytype/_search
{ 
"query": {
  "bool" : {
     "must" :[ 
      {
        "term" : { "unique_id" : "6324"}
      },
     {
        "term" : { "Date":"2015-09-17 03:45:00-04"}
      }
    ],
  }
}
}
```